# EntityType 'Worker' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My code is in `Solution.Models.Worker`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Solution.Models
{
    public class Worker
    { 
       public int AsmensKodas { get; set; }
       public string Vardas { get; set; }
       public string Pavarde { get; set; }
       public DateTime GimimoData { get; set; }
       public string Adresas { get; set; }
       public bool AktyvumoPozymis { get; set; } 
    }

    public class WorkerDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Worker> Worker { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I changed `web.config` file by adding

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WorkerDBContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Workers.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And when I try to add controller with "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework" with configuration

- Model class: `Worker` (Solution.Models)
- Data context class: `WorkerDbContext` (Solution.Models)
- Controller name: `WorkersController`

I get an error message saying

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Solution.Models.Worker.' One or more validation errors ware detected during model generation:
>   Solution.Models.Worker::EntityType 'Worker' has no key defined.
>   Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Workers:EntityType:EntitySet 'Workers' is based on type 'Worker' that has no keys defined.

Any suggestions what to do or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the Model's properties should be Key. So place `[Key]` annotation on top of one of the properties. Like this:

```
public class Worker
{ 
   [Key]
   public int AsmensKodas { get; set; }
   public string Vardas { get; set; }
   public string Pavarde { get; set; }
   public DateTime GimimoData { get; set; }
   public string Adresas { get; set; }
   public bool AktyvumoPozymis { get; set; } 

}
```

Just don't forget to add this line to your `using` directive:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Also if you have a property in your `Model` with name `Id`, you don't need to add the `[Key]` attribute to it.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the solution to be sure. The above should fix your problem. I would also do a manual clean, go into each of your project directories and delete any `bin` and `obj` folders, then rebuild.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, rebuild fixed it!

Comment: I am using ADO.NET EF 6.0 and having the model classes auto generated, so adding the '[Key]' annotation is problematic as every time I update the model it gets wiped out.  I have tried to add the annotation in an extension, but it does not work.  Is there a way to use this with autogenerated code?